# Is ETW streaming from Service Fabric cluster Diagnostic extension to Event Hubs currently possible?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, etw, azure-eventhub, azure-diagnostics

We are currently working to implement the sinking of Diagnostic streams into Event Hubs:

[image]

I have added the diagnostics extension to the service fabric cluster using the ARM template, and this is currently outputting to Azure storage, what I need now is set up the sink to the Event hub.

I followed this [post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-streaming-azure-diags-data/) , which describes how to add a `SinksConfig`  node to the diagnostics.wadcfgx file:

[image]

It seems however that this is only valid for Azure Cloud Service projects? In a cloud service project, it looks quite easy to add the config file by going to properties on the Role, and clicking enable Diagnostics to create the file:

[image]

With a Service Fabric project however, it is not possible to do this as there is no notion of a Web Role and there does not seem to be anywhere in the properties of the SF project where Diagnostics can be enabled/wadcfgx file added.

I have added the diagnostics extension to the VMs in the scale set by adding the following to the ARM template:

[image]

I can see where the storage account (where the ETW is currently being streamed to) is defined here, but I couldn’t find guidance on how to specify an Event Hub?

I did wonder whether this was just because it is not documented anywhere, or because it is not possible with Service Fabric yet. This [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/diagnostic-logs-streaming-to-event-hubs) , dated in July, states the following:

[image]

This seems to indicate this functionality may or may not be currently available for Service Fabric.

Summary

There are 2 main questions then:

1. Is it currently possible to set up ETW streaming from a Service Fabric cluster (with Diagnostics extension enabled) to an Event Hub? If not, how far away is it?
2. If it is possible, how should it be set up? If it is to be defined in the ARM template as defined above, what is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, it appears there are two ways to do this.

The steps from Visual Studio:

1. Locate your Scale Set in Cloud Explorer
2. Choose Update diagnostics
3. Record the current Storage Account being used
4. Edit your Public and Private config files for Event Hub sinks and storage account
5. Update diagnostics and choose to update based on the new config files

The public config is (only showing SinksConfig node for brevity)

```
{
 "WadCfg": {
     "DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration": {

     *** config for performance counters and ETW ***

       "SinksConfig": {
            "Sink": [
             {
               "name": "eventhub",
               "EventHub": {
               "Url": "https://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/mycompanyapplication",
               "SharedAccessKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     },
    "StorageAccount": "<storageaccount>"
}
```

and the private config:

```
{
   "storageAccountName": "<storageaccountname>",
   "storageAccountKey": "<storageaccountkey>",
   "storageAccountEndPoint": "https://core.windows.net",
   "EventHub": {
         "Url": "https://myhub.servicebus.windows.net/mycompanyapplication",
         "SharedAccessKeyName": "RootManageSharedAccessKey",
         "SharedAccessKey": "<sharedaccesskey>"
   }
}
```

Or this configuration can be made part of your ARM template, with the json from the public config copied into the "settings" node of the VMDiagnosticsSettings resource (example resource definition [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-extensions-diagnostics-template.md)), and the private config copied into the "protectedsettings" node.

Comment: Is it possible to only write to Eventhub? In EtwEventSourceProviderConfiguration we have defined few event provider’s destination as Storage Table, and for others we have configured eventhub sink. But we have observed WAD is pushing logs from all the event providers to TableStorage. Is this expected behavior?

For the providers where we have configured EventHub sink, can we prevent writing logs to Storage Table?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/tree/master/src/Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventListeners) example. Vaclav has created event listeners for various types of stores. Make sure you include the Nuget package '`Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource`' and replace '`System.Diagnostics.Tracing`' with '`Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing`' in your `ServiceEventSource` classes.
Register event providers in your ARM template like shown [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-management-party-cluster/blob/master/WADConfig/WadConfigUpdate.json).

Comment: Thanks for this, the approach you mention here does work but what I wanted to get to was getting the Diagnostics to sink into Event Hub through configuration as described here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/event-hubs-streaming-azure-diags-data/, rather than having a listener in the solution itself, the issue is that it doesn't seem possible in Service Fabric yet